# django migrating to 1.6 of an old app: ListView

Tags: django, listview, migration

I am migrating our old app to django 1.6.

Now, some views have been programmed this way:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

@render_to("items/index.html")
def index(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()    
    args = clean_url_encode(request.GET.copy().urlencode())
    context = {
        'is_dashboard': True,
        'body_id': 'dashboard',
        'object_list': None,
        'args':args,
        'show_in_process':False
    }
    return context
```

I know that I need to use the new ListView now, but the examples and docs don't seem to tell me this particular case I have: the object_list being passed in the context.

How can I adapt this code to use the new class based generic view? Can I also just use `ListView.asView()` instead of `'object_list':None ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `ListView` if you don't have a object list? I think `TemplateView` should do the job. You just need to override `get_context_data` and provide custom context

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'items/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = self.request.user.get_profile()
        args = clean_url_encode(self.request.GET.copy().urlencode())
        context.update({
            'is_dashboard': True,
            'body_id': 'dashboard',
            'object_list': None,
            'args':args,
            'show_in_process':False
        })
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks @tuxcanfly, so if I understand well, every such function becomes its own view class? That would be quite a bit to migrate for us...

Comment: I see. Not all functions, just the generic views.